# How do you unsubscribe to apollo observable in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, graphql, apollo

I'm building an angular (4.x) application using apollo-angular, and I'm wondering how to unsubscribe from apollo observables (if you need to at all).

I'm trying to follow the guidance in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163/5141687) by creating a query:

```
this.query = this.apollo.watchQuery<LatestReportQueryResponse>({
  fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
  query: myQuery
});
```

Assigning a new subject:

```
  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
```

Subscribing to the query:

```
this.query.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(({ data }) => {...}
```

and then destroying all active observables on a `onDestroy` event cycle with something like:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
```

After adding the `.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)`, I  run into lint errors like:

> Argument of type 'Subject' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable'.

Or when I try to manually unsubscribe to the ApolloQueryObservable, I get:

> Property 'unsubscribe' does not exist on type 'ApolloQueryObservable'. Did you mean 'subscribe'?

Is unsubscribing necessary for apollo observables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value of `this.query.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(...)` should give you the unsubscribe function.

subscribe and save unsubscribe function:

`this.unsubscribe = this.query.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(...)`

on the `onDestroy` event cycle, call the function:

`this.unsubscribe()`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I currently have the setup you described-- however, when I however over the "this.query" (before the takeunti()) typescript complains with:  "The 'this' context of type 'ApolloQueryObservable<QueryResponse>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type Observable<ApolloQueryResult<QueryResponse>>'. Is there any way to confirm that an observable is completed/destroyed?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure if it can be confirmed. Maybe it is written in the [API](http://dev.apollodata.com/angular2)

Comment: This is wrong. You don't need to unsubscribe if you have a takeUntil. Once the takeUntil meets its callback, it auto unsubs. You could just set `this.ngUnsubscribe = false;`  in your answer, `this.unsubscribe()` would fail as it's not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is answering this is a more specific scenario that explains more to this question, so adding this below blog link here.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-takeuntil-rxjs-unsubscribe

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { from, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export class CalendarWeekViewStdComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
private subscriptionName: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
this.subscriptionName = this.settingService.diarySettings.subscribe(settings => {

 });
}
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
if (this.subscriptionName) {
      this.subscriptionName.unsubscribe();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a clean way that we use often that enable you to dispose of the second observable `ngUnsubscribe`.

It consists of
1- storing your subscription in a property of type : `Subscription`,
2 - on destroy you have to call the function subscribe of this propoerty.

you can use array if you have more than one subscription

```
import { from, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
ngOnInit() {
this.subscriptions.push( this.settingService.diarySettings.subscribe(settings => {

 }));
}
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
 }
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it but one small change.   `private subscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription();` instead of setting it to an array, and `this.subscriptions.add` instead of `.push`. then you don't have to forEach, you just say `this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();` and it will unsub to all.